# How to size a panel to fit a grid

Tags: python, wxpython, sizer, wxnotebook, wxgrid

Here is the simplest example I can make of what I am trying to do.   It is a grid inside a panel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import wx.grid

app = wx.App(False)  

class InfoPane(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent)

        # Set up the presentation
        self.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        self.CreateGrid(1, 6)

        self.SetColLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_LEFT, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        self.SetColLabelValue(0, "Name")
        self.SetColLabelValue(1, "Status")
        self.SetColLabelValue(2, "")
        self.SetColLabelValue(3, "File")
        self.SetColLabelValue(4, "Last Action")
        self.SetColLabelValue(5, "Other Info")

frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
info_pane = InfoPane(panel)

note_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
note_sizer.Add(info_pane, 1, wx.EXPAND)

panel.SetSizerAndFit(note_sizer)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

I want the whole thing to size itself so that the contents of the grid are all visible.   What happens at the moment is this:

[image: screenie]

(note: edit - I took the notebook out, for even more simplification, the result is the same looking)

Ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: why not enlarge your window when you create it? frame = wx.Frame(None,size=(1000,1000))

Comment: Because I want the app to start up the correct size.    Too big: lots of yucky whitespace around the grid (try it with the example code, I think you will see what I mean).   Too small: scroll bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a sizer to the frame when you call the fit method on the frame it will size to its children.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import wx.grid

app = wx.App(False)


class InfoPane(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent)

        # Set up the presentation
        self.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        self.CreateGrid(1, 6)

        self.SetColLabelAlignment(wx.ALIGN_LEFT, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.SetColLabelValue(0, "Name")
        self.SetColLabelValue(1, "Status")
        self.SetColLabelValue(2, "")
        self.SetColLabelValue(3, "File")
        self.SetColLabelValue(4, "Last Action")
        self.SetColLabelValue(5, "Other Info")

frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
info_pane = InfoPane(panel)

note_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
note_sizer.Add(info_pane, 1, wx.EXPAND)

panel.SetSizer(note_sizer)
frame_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
frame_sizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
frame.SetSizerAndFit(frame_sizer)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Sweet!   That's what I was looking for.   Is the essence of this answer that I was setting the size of the panel, but not the frame, and it is the frame that needed resizing?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size of the Grid and resize its parent panel with it.

Try this:

```
panel.SetSizerAndFit(note_sizer)
gridSize = info_pane.GetVirtualSize()
frame.Show() 
panel.SetSize(gridSize)
frame.Fit()
```